# Telling a pivot page which page to open on via xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I navigate to my pivote page by doing this

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PivotScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there a simple way to tell it which pageto open on it there are 5 pages on that pivot?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `thisPivot.SelectedIndex =  0;` should do it.

**Edit**

I will add code to clarify.

.xaml file

```
 <controls:Pivot Name="thisPivot" Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="second"> 
            <!--Triple line list no text wrapping-->
                <ListBox x:Name="SecondListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

Code behind

```
// Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        thisPivot.SelectedIndex = 1;

        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thisPivot should be? The name of the .xaml that is the pivot?

Comment: I dont see thisPivot declard in the code anywhere. Should thisPivot.SelectedIndex = 0; actually read pvcontrol.SelectedIndex = 0; so that the code and xaml match up? Or does it not matter?

Comment: That is correct.  Whatever you have as your Name attribute on the pivot control in the XAML is how you reference it in the code.  Thats why I posted a full example of the code. I will modify my code example to 100% match my first response